# bootstrap - overlay popover inside modal header

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I was trying to add overlay popover inside modal header. but when popover was shown, the popover ignores the its original position.

HTML

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
        aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <div class="pull-right">
      <div class="overlay">
          <a class="btn"
              rel="popover" 
              href="#"
              name="link-menu"
              data-content="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. " 
              data-original-title="A Title"
              data-placement="bottom">
                  popover menu
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>    
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting                                        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
</div>
```

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.overlay.on {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Here's a fiddle of what I have been able to achieve. 
http://jsfiddle.net/rjrimorin/p6BAD/50/

Any help is greatly APPRECIATED! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p6BAD/51/)

remove `position: relative` from overlay class and change  `position: fixed` to  `position: static` for `.overlay.on`

```
$('a[rel=popover]').popover();

  $("a[name='link-menu']").click(function() {
    $("div.overlay").toggleClass("on");
  });
```

```css
.btn{
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.overlay {
 position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.overlay.on {
  position: static;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
            aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <div class="overlay">
              <a class="btn"
                  rel="popover" 
                  href="#"
                  name="link-menu"
                  data-content="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. " 
                  data-original-title="A Title"
                  data-placement="bottom">
                      popover menu
              </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>    
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
```

Comment: Hi Neophyte, thanks for the answer but I need the overlay so that when popover shows up it will only focus on the popover and the modal will be unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

May be this:

```
.btn{
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.overlay.on {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 10;
}

.overlay.on {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
} 
.popover.fade.bottom.in {
  width: 250px;
  left: -50% !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi rinatoptimus, thanks for the answer, the overlay is gone, I need the overlay so that the user can only focus on the popover and the modal will be unclickable.